# Can an Apple Watch configured with Family Setup use the other family members' iPad?

Tags: apple-watch

My child has an iPad with his own Apple Id. I'm considering getting him an Apple Watch, but controlled from my iPhone using Family Setup. My question is if the watch can sync/communicate with his iPad? On the iPad he has his podcasts, books, music, etc., and that is what we would like to appear on his watch.

I've read the documentation, but I'm still unclear on how that would work.

Comment: That syncing should be possible over the internet, not directly between the iPad and the Watch. If (independent of the iPad) the watch can do Podcasts and Music without an iPhone (using family setup) then the iPad should hook into that equation as another device syncing with iCloud.

Comment: @EzekielElin The documentation (https://support.apple.com/guide/books/books-audiobooks-devices-ibks86dab303/mac) says the watch would sync over bluetooth (see second paragraph). Would you still hold to your comment?